# How can I fix this Python elif statement syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to write a calculator to calculate a formula in Python, but I am getting a syntax error for my elif statement. I have checked on several other posts on here and other sites, but it seems people are making different mistakes than me. Thanks for your help in advance! :)  Here is my code:

```
# IMPORTS

import os
import math

# SELECTION

print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("~~~ PYTHAGOREAN THEOROM CALCULATOR ~~~")
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("OPTIONS:")
print ("1 - SOLVE FOR HYPOTENUSE")
print ("2 - SOLVE FOR LEG")
print ("3 - SOLVE FOR LEG 2")

user_choice = input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE: ")

# HYPOTENUSE MATHEMATICS

if user_choice == "1":
    firstnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR FIRST LEG'S DIMENSION: "))
    secondnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR SECOND LEG'S DIMENSION: "))

secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)

hanswer = math.sqrt(secondsteph)

print (hanswer , "IS YOUR ANSWER")

input()
os.system('cls')

# LEG 1 MATHEMATICS

elif user_choice == "2":
    firstnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR LEG: "))
    secondnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR HYPOTENUSE: "))

secondstepl = (secondnl ** 2 - firstnl ** 2)

lanswer = math.sqrt(secondstepl)

print (lanswer, "IS YOUR ANSWER")

input()
os.system('cls')
```

The error is here:

```
# LEG 1 MATHEMATICS

elif user_choice == "2":  < - - - ERROR HERE
    firstnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR LEG: "))
    secondnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR HYPOTENUSE: "))

secondstepl = (secondnl ** 2 - firstnl ** 2)

lanswer = math.sqrt(secondstepl)

print (lanswer, "IS YOUR ANSWER")

input()
os.system('cls')
```

This is what the IDE says:

```
elif user_choice == "2":
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't have an `if` statement, execute general statements outside of that `if` statement and then extend the `if` with `elif`. Put code specific to the first case in the block after the `if` statement (indentation is relevant!) and put general code to be executed in any case after the `if`-`elif`-`else` structure.

Comment: `elif` should next to `if` statement

Comment: You have intermediate after the  `if` that is no part of the `if`. And elif can follow directly an if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage is wrong, the `elif` statement must only be used after an if statement.

```
if user_choice == "1":
    firstnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR FIRST LEG'S DIMENSION: "))
    secondnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR SECOND LEG'S DIMENSION: "))
```

This part is only in the `if` statement.
From the line `secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)` onward, it is a new block of code, not in the if block. If this is an indentation error, Try :

```
if user_choice == "1":
    firstnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR FIRST LEG'S DIMENSION: "))
    secondnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR SECOND LEG'S DIMENSION: "))

    secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)

    hanswer = math.sqrt(secondsteph)

    print (hanswer , "IS YOUR ANSWER")

    input()
    os.system('cls')

# LEG 1 MATHEMATICS

elif user_choice == "2":
    firstnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR LEG: "))
    secondnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR HYPOTENUSE: "))
```

If not, place the statements,

```
secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)

hanswer = math.sqrt(secondsteph)

print (hanswer , "IS YOUR ANSWER")

input()
os.system('cls')
```

after the `elif` block

Comment: It was an indention error, I just needed to indent to extra code in there. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unindented code between the if and the elif clauses:

```
secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)

hanswer = math.sqrt(secondsteph)

print (hanswer , "IS YOUR ANSWER")

input()
os.system('cls')
```

Answer (score 0):

if and elif have to be in the same indentation level:

```
if <condition>:
    something
elif <condition>:
    somethingelse
```

You can't write code in between like this:

```
if <condition>:
    something

print()
variable = "something"

elif <condition>:
    somethingelse
```

then your code will be:

```
# HYPOTENUSE MATHEMATICS

if user_choice == "1":
    firstnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR FIRST LEG'S DIMENSION: "))
    secondnh = int(input("ENTER YOUR SECOND LEG'S DIMENSION: "))

    secondsteph = (firstnh ** 2 + secondnh **2)

    hanswer = math.sqrt(secondsteph)

    print (hanswer , "IS YOUR ANSWER")

    input()
    os.system('cls')

# LEG 1 MATHEMATICS

elif user_choice == "2":
    firstnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR LEG: "))
    secondnl = int(input("ENTER YOUR HYPOTENUSE: "))

    secondstepl = (secondnl ** 2 - firstnl ** 2)

    lanswer = math.sqrt(secondstepl)

    print (lanswer, "IS YOUR ANSWER")

    input()
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to say thank you for the help, I really appreciate it. I didn't understand at first, but once I began thinking straight it was clear as day. I'd also like to thank everyone else that contributed. Have a good day! (I even learned a little about the 8th-grade level algebra formula I was using haha)